# "Hide" files in executables (C++)

Tags: c++, file, driver, hide

Is there any way to kind of "hide" things in executables?
For example adding dll's to your project.
These files such as a driver, a dll and another executable should somehow get extracted, be used and deleted after that.
Im using VS2015 and I try to hide the files in a x86 c++ application.

Comment: For me, personally, this sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378). Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Well, If I have several executables laying around and the user doesn't actually know which one to open, he might screw some stuff up, so I would like to just have 1 executable and he openes it and then it will go on by itself, launch updater, loading driver and all that stuff

Comment: can you not just create a SFX with something like Winrar?

Comment: You can add them in resource section

Comment: @MarcelMar That's where having decent documentation and/or folder structure helps.

Comment: I was thinking about the resource thing too, but I forgot about it again lol. Im gonna try it out later.

Comment: If you want only an executable, you could statically link the libraries used and skip the dlls.

Comment: Of course you can. You can store arbitrary chunks of data inside an executable, so of course you could stick another executable, a dll or an image in there and access it later.The question is whether it's a good idea or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could use resources. [FindResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042(v=vs.85).aspx) is the main function for extracting the file from resources. I assume you want to insert a resource by hand, not programatically. And so:

Inserting binary resource in c++:
In your .rc file of the project:

```
IDR_BIN             BIN      DISCARDABLE     "file.exe"
```

Extracting binary resource in c++:

```
bool ExtractBinResource( std::string strCustomResName, int nResourceId, std::wstring strOutputName )
{
    HGLOBAL hResourceLoaded = NULL;     // handle to loaded resource 
    HRSRC hRes = NULL;                      // handle/ptr. to res. info. 
    char *lpResLock = NULL;             // pointer to resource data 
    DWORD dwSizeRes;

    // find location of the resource and get handle to it
    hRes = FindResourceA( NULL, MAKEINTRESOURCEA(nResourceId), strCustomResName.c_str() );
    if (hRes == NULL) return false;
    // loads the specified resource into global memory. 
    hResourceLoaded = LoadResource( NULL, hRes ); 
    if (hResourceLoaded == NULL) return false;
    // get a pointer to the loaded resource!
    lpResLock = (char*)LockResource( hResourceLoaded ); 
    if (lpResLock == NULL) return false;
    // determine the size of the resource, so we know how much to write out to file!  
    dwSizeRes = SizeofResource( NULL, hRes );

    std::ofstream outputFile(strOutputName.c_str(), std::ios::binary);

    outputFile.write((const char*)lpResLock, dwSizeRes);
    outputFile.close();
    return true;
}
```

Where in this case `strCustomResName` is `"BIN"` and `nResourceId` is what number you chose to #define `IDR_BIN`

If by 'hide' you mean that nobody could see/understand what's in your executable then you should also encrypt your file.